# Why after migrating to EF Core 3.1 eager loading not working

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

Recently migrated EF core from 2.2 to 3.1 and the following query is not loading child entites. I get only parent level data.
What could be the problem?

```
var query = DBContext.Books
            .Include(t => t.Reviews)
            .ThenInclude(u=> u.User)                
            .FirstOrDefault(book => book.ID == 279);
```

The generated SQL is picking up the navigation property, as it generates the correct sql JOIN for the correct properties... Just that when it comes back into C#, for some reason it's not picking up and populating the JOINed values.

Many to many mapping is not working properly.

Comment: how can you call `Include` on a DbContext? `Include` is only valid on `IQueryable`.

Comment: corrected it. Thanks

Comment: Similar queries work fine for me in EF Core 3.1; there must be something odd within your entities. Can you post the relevant parts of the entity classes?

Comment: Double-check that the actual connection string at runtime is pointing at the database instance you think it is. Often a connection string gets updated in a DLL's config file but doesn't flow through to the running application config.

Comment: One-to-Many and Many-to-Many relations are not working properly

Comment: When I created fresh project and used EF Core 3.1, it works. But not with migrated project.

Answer (score 0):

Found the part of code that was creating the issue. Actually it was the constructor in the mapping class that created the issue. *I had to remove the constructor in order to make it work.*

I had mapping class something like this.

```
public class BookCategory
{
    public BookCategory() //Removed the constructor to make it work
    { 
       Book = new Book();
       Category = new Category();
    }
    public int BookId { get; set; }
    public Book Book { get; set; }
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public Category Category { get; set; }
}
```

Same class worked for EF Core 2.2 but not for 3.1. Reason why it is not working in 3.1 is unclear to me yet.